# Shift cipher in C++ (How to get ASCII value and handling numbers)

Tags: c++, encryption, vector, ascii, shift

I have a program set up already to read in a file and split each line into words, storing them into a double vector of strings. That is,

```
std::vector < std::vector <std::string> > words
```

So, the idea is to use an array from alphabet a-z and using the ASCII values of the letters to get the index and swapping the characters in the strings with the appropriate shifted character. How would I get the value of each character so that I can look it up as an index?

I also want to keep numbers intact, as a shift cipher, I believe, doesn't do anything with numbers in the text to be deciphered. How would I check if the character is an int so I can leave it alone?

Comment: It seems like you're asking how to obtain the ascii value of a single character of one of the strings in your vector of vectors of strings.  `cout << static_cast<unsigned>(words[0][0][1]) << "\n";` would print the ascii value of the second character in the first string in your vector of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ASCII value, you simply have to cast the value to a `int`:

```
int ascii_value = (int)words[i][j][k];
```

If you want to have a value starting from `A` or `a` you can do this:

```
int letter_value_from_A = (int)(words[i][j][k] - 'A');
int letter_value_from_a = (int)(words[i][j][k] - 'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your char is nothing else than a value. Take this code as example (I am used to program [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), so this will be a little ugly):

```
char shiftarray[256] = {0, 0, 0, 0 // Here comes your map //
std::string output;

for(int w=0; w<words.length(); w++)
{
   for(int c=0; c<words[w].length(); c++)
   {
      output.pushback(shiftarry[words[w][c]]);
   }
   output.push_back(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do it in anything other than basic, but very simply get the ascii value of each letter in the string using a loop. As the loop continues add a value to, or subtract a value from the ascii value you just obtained, then convert it back to a letter and append it to a string. This will give you a different character than you had originally. By doing this, you can load and save data that will look like gibberish if anyone tried to view it other than in the program it was written in. The data then becomes a special propriatry document format.